# Flattening the tree

Tags: c++

Flattening the data: How to write a recursive function that returns a linked list of nodes, when given a binary tree of nodes? (The tree can be modified)

In this questioning what does the flattening the tree mean? Is it we need to maintain all the elements of a binary tree in a list with its left and right pointers or there is another catch which i am not getting?

Secondly (the tree can be modified) does they mean the fun should be able to handle any modification of tree along with build?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a binary tree like so:

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 / \   \
0   0   d
       / \
      0   0
```

Where `a`, `b`, etc. are nodes and `0` is nil. There are several possible recursive [traversals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) of the tree:

- Pre-order, visiting parents before children: `a b c d`
- In-order, visiting parents between children: `b a c d`
- Post-order, visiting parents after children: `b d c a`

A “flattening” of a tree is merely a list resulting from a traversal; your data structure is no longer nested, but flat instead. To flatten a tree, begin with an empty linked list. Then traverse the tree in the order of your choosing, appending each visited node to the linked list. I presume “the tree can be modified” means that your function may alter the tree as it builds the list, if you find it necessary to do so.

Comment: but in what scenarios our fun will alter the tree?

Comment: @cexplorer: It is not necessary to alter it; the linked list may contain copies of each node from the tree. If copying causes performance problems, the algorithm can be written to avoid copying, either by sharing, or by editing the tree in place such that it takes the shape of a linked list.

Answer (score 3):

Flattening just means they want the nodes in a linear order. There are several common orderings of a tree: preorder, inorder, or postorder, where the parent node appears before, in between, or after its children respectively.